# React getElementById mysteriously failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating my own React class component for the first time, and for some reason its id doesn't "take".

```
import React, { Component, forwardRef } from 'react';

class FilterGroup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    result() {
        return ("some-text");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                (deleted a lot of stuff)
            </>
        )
    }
}

function App () {
    function read () {
        var filters = document.getElementById("filters")
        var result = filters.result()
        console.log(result);
    }

    return(
        <div>
        <button onClick={read}>
        Read
        </button>
        <FilterGroup id="filters"/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

When I click the Read button, I get an error, because document.getElementById("filters") has returned null.
Seems to me, the read () function is called **long** after the DOM has been loaded and established, and my constructor is properly passing along the props, so I don't understand how the id got lost. What happened?

Comment: You shouldnt be using getElementById with react, you should be saving the values from filters in a state and pulling them from there

Comment: a) You should not be using `getElementById`, use a ref. b) `getElementById` would return an `HTMLElement`, not an instance of whatever class you are using. c) What is `FilterGroup` doing with the `id` prop? d) Instance methods on your class components should not be called by anything else except for the instance itself. e) Consider using functional components, which discourage this kind of antipattern.

Comment: Well that's interesting, because I've seen LOTS of examples using getElementById with React. I thought it was entirely normal!

Although I compressed it out of this example, the intent of FilterGroup.result() is actually to return a textified form of the state of FilterGroup. So Richard, vr, I need an example. With or without using refs, what is a good way for App to ask FilterGroup to deliver its state?

Comment: Show us those examples.

Answer (score 0):

`FilterGroup` is a component, not an HTML element, so the `id` is passed as a prop, not as an HTML attribute.

So, in the `FilterGroup` component, you need to pass the `id` prop to the element you want to assign the `id` for.

For example

```
const FilterGroup = ({ id }) => {
  return <div id={id}>Filter group content</div>
}
export default FilterGroup
```

`var result = filters.result()`
Also, there is no `results()` method in the element object.

Also, I suggest you use [`refs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead of using native javascript dom query methods

Comment: What about the `result` method they are trying to call?

Comment: @vr. Yes will produce an error, I just update the answer, thanks for notifying me.